# What does EIP stand for?

Tags: exploit, assembly

There are a *ton* of questions on here that make reference to the `eip`:

- [How can I partially overwrite the EIP in order to bypass ASLR?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117250/how-can-i-partially-overwrite-the-eip-in-order-to-bypass-aslr?rq=1)
- [Unable to overwrite EIP register](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121242/unable-to-overwrite-eip-register?rq=1)
- [Do I always have to overwrite EIP to get to write on the stack in a buffer overflow?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23039/do-i-always-have-to-overwrite-eip-to-get-to-write-on-the-stack-in-a-buffer-overf?rq=1)
- Etc.

What is the EIP? How is it used, both as an exploit target and in benign code?

Comment: I googled `eip` and came up with nothing interesting. I can come up with a better search string, but I know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, I opened with a search followed by a search on here. EIP means too many things, even `eip computer science` returns nothing useful. When I realized this _very_ basic question had not been asked here, I thought it would be valuable for both me and anyone else browsing the site.

Comment: Search for "eip assembly" instead and you will get more information than you will ever be able to read ;) !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

EIP is a register in x86 architectures (32bit). It holds the "Extended Instruction Pointer" for the stack. In other words, it tells the computer where to go next to execute the next command and controls the flow of a program.

Research Assembly language to get a better understanding of how registers work. [Skull Security](https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/index.php?title=Registers) has a good primer.

Comment: What does RIP stand for?

Comment: @Shayan: although it has another (wider) meaning, in this context it is the 64-bit form of 'register' IP in x86-64 (aka amd64); compare the two sections starting at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit

Answer (score 20):

One of the basic things that a computer needs to keep track of is where in memory are located the instructions currently being executed.

This is normally done by the *CPU* using what is often known as the `Instruction Pointer` or `Program counter` [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). The exact name depends on the architecture, but the concept generalizes across all architectures. It's called the *Instruction Pointer* on *Intel CPUs*, and that's the term I'll be using in this answer.

The instruction pointer is continually incremented while instructions are executed from memory, and also updated whenever a jump instruction of some kind is executed (`jmp`, `jle`, etc.). Modern *CPU* architectures with multiple parallel execution pipelines and multiple cores makes what is actually going on inside the *CPU* more complex, but to an external observer, the simple explanation is sufficient to understand what is going on and the purpose of the relevant registers.

By virtue of the old `Intel 8086/8088`, `80186` and `80286` being *16-bit* processors, the instruction pointer was normally expressed as a pair of *16-bit* values known as the `Code Segment` (code *selector* in the `80286`, but except in protected mode selectors function very similarly to segments) and instruction pointer.

In assembler parlace, `CS:IP` where the colon indicates the pairing of a segment and an offset as a pair to form a memory address. `CS` and `IP` here are *CPU Registers* - tiny memory locations within the CPU chip itself - in this particular case each *16 bits* in size.

You also had things like `DS:DX` which was conventionally the location to where to read or write data in memory; `DS` was *data segment* and `DX` is a general-purpose register that in this case held the data segment offset. There were originally four registers intended for general use, referred to as `AX`, `BX`, `CX` and `DX` respectively, each of which could be addressed in terms of the high half -- `AH`, for example -- or the low half -- `AL`, plus a small number of general-purpose registers that had specific intended uses. Modern CPUs have many, many more registers, with dozens of registers being common and over a hundred not unheard of.

In making the `80386` CPU in the late 1980s, Intel made a lot of changes, including extending the address space to 32 bits *while keeping selectors as a concept*. For this reason, the old 16-bit values were no longer sufficient, and the instruction pointer was extended to 32 bits. In order to maintain full backward compatibility (at this point, Intel had probably learned the lesson of the 80286 which was more one-way compatible; it was easy to go from the `8086/8088`'s *real mode* into the `80286`'s *protected mode*, but going back was a lot more difficult, and this turned out to be a problem in practice), this required a new register for the CPU to keep the instruction pointer when operating in 32-bit mode.

In the `80386`, the extended *(32-bit)* registers were named `Exx` whereas the corresponding *16-bit* registers were as previously referred to as *xx*. So you'd get for example the old 16-bit accumulator register AX plus the extended 32-bit accumulator register `EAX` (with `AX` as the low *16-bit* half). In keeping with this naming convention, **the *Extended Instruction Pointer* register was referred to as `EIP`.**

As an aside, most often, the correct value isn't merely `EIP`, but `CS:EIP`, because the value of `EIP` remains an *offset* from some starting location which is defined by the code selector.

Comment: Hundreds of registers??? When I thought there were only a few. Eax, Ecx, Edx and Ebx.